# curl return false on hosting

Tags: php, curl

I want to get some data from server with curl (from Hosting). But i rceive always false. I run this script on my PC then it works clearly.

```
$curl = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
$response = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl);  
var_dump($response);  
exit();
```

Comment: Use [curl_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to check for an error message

Comment: What is the curl command that is error-ing out plz?